# Multiple robots simulation in Stage with amcl navigation

Tags: navigation, simulation, stage, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to set two robots on the map and use amcl navigation for each of them. As a role model, I used [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/) (it deals with the same situation in Gazebo).

After creating a .yaml and .world files with a map and two robots on it, I created a launch file that uses namespaces and tf_prefix.
The final list of topics is as expected.

The trouble is with frames: there is no /map frame, nor the link from it to robot_0/odom and robot_1/odom. As far as I know, the responsibility for publishing that frame is on amcl but can't figure out why it fails to publish it.
(The warning received is:

> Timed out waiting for transform from
> robot_0/base_footprint to map to
> become available before running
> costmap, tf error: . canTransform
> returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.

UPDATE: managed to make it work with fake localization (by taking [this example](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/navigation_stage/launch/move_base_multi_robot.launch) as is and adding custom .yaml and .world files. The question remains: how to add amcl into it?
If I use fake_localization for one robot, and amcl for the other one, the tf tree looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11955498/frames.pdf)

Please, help me with any hint on how frames actually work and why could it be that there is transformation from /map frame to robot_0/odom (the one that uses amcl)

The launch files are is as below:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="map_file" default=" $(find demo_1)/stageSetup/maze.yaml" />
    <arg name="world_file" default="$(find demo_1)/stageSetup/stage/maze.world" />
    <master auto="start" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

    <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"
        respawn="false">
        <param name="frame_id" value="/map" />
    </node>

    <node pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros" name="stageros"
        args="$(arg world_file)"
        respawn="false">
        <param name="base_watchdog_timeout" value="0.2" />
    </node>

    <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 0 -->
    <group ns="robot_0">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_0" />

        <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node"
            output="screen">
            <remap from="map" to="/map" />
            <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml"
                command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml"
                command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/local_costmap_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/global_costmap_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/base_local_planner_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
        </node>
        <!-- 
        <node pkg="fake_localization" type="fake_localization" name="fake_localization"
            respawn="false" output="screen">
            <param name="odom_frame_id" value="robot_0/odom" />
            <param name="base_frame_id" value="robot_0/base_link" />
        </node>
         -->
         <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
            <remap from="static_map" to="/static_map"/>
            <remap from="map" to="/map"/>
         </node>
         
    </group>
    <!-- END ROBOT 0 -->

    <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 1 -->
    <group ns="robot_1">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_1" />

        <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node"
            output="screen">
            <remap from="map" to="/map" />
            <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml"
                command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml"
                command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/local_costmap_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/global_costmap_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
            <rosparam
                file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/base_local_planner_params.yaml"
                command="load" />
        </node>

        <node pkg="fake_localization" type="fake_localization" name="fake_localization"
            respawn="false">
            <param name="odom_frame_id" value="robot_1/odom" />
            <param name="base_frame_id" value="robot_1/base_link" />
        </node>
    </group>
    <!-- END ROBOT 1 -->
 
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"
        args="-d $(find navigation_stage)/multi_robot.rviz" />


</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227728/multiple-robots-simulation-in-stage-with-amcl-navigation/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Try to modify your amcl node to:

```
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
  <remap from="static_map" to="/static_map"/>

  <param name="global_frame_id" value="/map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="robot_0/odom"/>
  <param name="base_frame_id" value="robot_0/base_link"/>
</node>
```

Replace robot_0 in the last two params to robot_1 for the second robot's amcl node.

---

Originally posted by [Dany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26578/dany/) with karma: 46 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-05-01**:
Thank you! I am accepting this answer as it solves the tf-tree trouble. However, with this change, there is another problem - complaining about robot being out of map. I will have to investigate it further.

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-05-01**:
However, I managed to solve the initial problem coming from another direction, and the example code is [on github](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_stage_amcl). Seems that putting tf_prefix directly to amcl node did the trick (but not sure as the same thing didn't work in initial code)